# How to validate an Exception occurred as expected in a Unity Test?

Tags: unity, c#, exceptions, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit tests in Unity that assert that logs, errors, and exceptions are raised as expected in my code, but I'm getting inconsistent results.

I'm using `LogAssert.Expect(LogType, string)` for each different kind of message. Logs and Errors work - if I expect a log/error with a particular message, then log/error with that same message, the test passes.

```
[UnityTest] //Passes
public IEnumerator LogMessage()
{
    LogAssert.Expect(LogType.Log, "message");
    Debug.Log("message");
    yield return null;
}

[UnityTest] //Passes
public IEnumerator LogError()
{
    LogAssert.Expect(LogType.Error, "error");
    Debug.LogError("error");
    yield return null;
}
```

But when I try expecting an exception, then `LogException()` with a `new Exception()` with a matching message, the test still fails:

```
[UnityTest] //Fails
public IEnumerator LogException()
{
    LogAssert.Expect(LogType.Exception, "");
    Debug.LogException(new Exception(""));
    yield return null;
}
```

What do I need to change so that the exception is correctly matched as the one I was expecting, satisfying the test?